# Widfly -> URL should be only mywebapp ? How is it possible?

Tags: jboss, dns, server

I would like to do following:

I have a Standalone Wildfly which runs on my local PC. This PC has a static IP Address (e.g. 192.168.178.2.11)

Now I would like to open my WebApp also from another PC. This works fine. (I´ve adjust the standalone.xml to "any-address").

Now I have following problem:
I can open the WebApp only with following URL:

**Computer on which runs my WebApp:** localhost:8080

**Other computer:** 192.168.178.2.11:8080

But I would like to have:

**Computer on which runs my WebApp:** mywebapp.com

**Other computer:** mywebapp.com

Is it possible to have also only: mywebapp (without .com) ?
How can I do this?
Can anybody please help me step by step. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your webserver on the default ports (80 for HTTP) and register your desired name on the DNS server in your local network for your PCs IP address.